# Bulk font-replace double-wide Chinese-encoded fonts?

Tags: fonts, microsoft-powerpoint, encoding, microsoft-office-2019

### Goal:

I'm trying to script or use a built-in operation to bulk replace fonts within a PowerPoint file (a set of files, really).

### Steps/code:

I've found the com object code to create a powerpoint object and change the font of the selected text; also, I've found an in-app "font replace" option; also, I used macro software and manually changed the font.

### The problem:

For some reason (probably encoding), the fonts are reverting back to YaHei/SimSun, even though their appearance takes on the selected (i.e., Wingdings) font.  Check out this image: the text area is clearly written in Wingdings, but the font-face menu option reads "SimSun".

[image: Image described in-context, sir.]

Why is it a problem?  Because the characters are treated as glyphs!  So, <kbd>ctrl+dpad</kbd> doesn't navigate full words.

The "font replace" option does not allow me to choose any non-glyph fonts for some of the fonts to be replaced, which greatly diminishes my options.  So, basically I can change the appearance, but I can't change the functionality of the textareas.

### Proposed solutions?

Maybe changing the encoding somewhere can help?

Comment: PowerPoint won't allow you to replace a double-byte font with a single-byte font; logical to some extent because it prevents users from inadvertently trashing text. Less than useful when the double-byte font doesn't really NEED to be there.

Comment: My findings are similar.  I move the text to a notepad instance and then bring it back to Powerpoint, but I also need to create a new presentation because the presentation file itself is set up for these fonts.  Changing the fonts on the presentation didn't have a global effect, and I hope there's some way that users can make a global change like that mentioned in the future because there were a lot of thematic elements that I couldn't bring into the new presentation.

Comment: As it happens, I've been (sporadically) working on a way of replacing unwanted fonts with other fonts, regardless of single-/double-byteness etc. Some of the Asian fonts pose a special problem because of the way they're represented internally in the XML that makes up a PPTX. If you've got a simple, one-slide example of the problem, I'd be interested in having a go at it.  If so, please post it on OneDrive/Dropbox/wherever and post an "anyone with this link can download the file" link here.